# The Dock was moved to the right side of the screen but still auto displays when cursor on bottom?

Tags: dock

Using this tip from basic Google Search I was able to move the Dock to the right side:

[image]

The Dock *does* show only on the right side now.  However it *also* displays (**auto-unhides**) when the mouse/cursor travels to the ***bottom*** of the screen.

It is distracting when interacting with full length windows. Can that behavior be disabled?  I am on Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get unexpected behaviour after manually moving or adjusting the Dock, you can try restarting the Dock.

Open your **Terminal** (*Applications > Other > Terminal* or search for **Terminal** in **Spotlight**)

Type `killall Dock` after the prompt and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Your Dock should restart with the expected behaviour.  You can verify your settings in the **System Preferences > Dock**

**Edit:** It May be necessary to reset the Dock to factory settings then customize as needed. Some have experienced various [dock bugs in Sierra](https://medium.com/@julioromano/working-around-an-infamous-macos-sierra-dock-bug-a957fe8a806f).

1. Open the Terminal
2. Type (or copy and paste) `defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock`
3. Hit <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: `killall dock` did not find any processes.  Instead `killall Dock` *did* .. including `Application Switcher`.  I have no idea how to restart those without rebooting.

Comment: It should restart on it's own after a few seconds.  You'll notice in my answer that it is Dock with a Capital 'D'.  Cheers

Comment: Also, just for the record, please update your question with the version of macOS you are using.

Comment: OK I missed that were in caps. The Dock did not restart .. after ten minutes now.

Comment: That seems to indicate that you have a more serious issue than normal. If a reboot does not fix the issue someone with a bit more process know-how may have further answers.

Comment: reboot did work. I will award because yours is probably the correct general solution.

Comment: I’ll research and update the answer too. I hope you find a solution. Cheers!